# Authentication and Authorization + Asp.net Web API + AngularJS + Windows Authentication + Login Form + Custom User and Role Tables

Tags: c#, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api

Planning to implement token based authentication for the angularjs and webapi project we are going to develop an internal enterprise application.

We have a requirement to implement Authentication which will work on

- windows authentication when accessed from within the network (internal network)
- and show login form if accessed from external network.

We have user and role tables in SQL database. we need authenticate against the Active Directory but use the user info and role info from the SQL database.

Here is the plan I have in mind

1. Check the source of request
2. If Internal use System.UserName and get user and role info from SQL db
3. If external show login form, allow user to enter username and password. Check against Active Directory using the entered username and password. If success get common name from active directory and use it to get user and role info from the SQL db.

How can we implement token based authentication for angularjs and webapi application ?

Comment: I also have a token based authentication in my application I'm currently developing. Here's a nice tutorial i followed for this: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: I am trying to implement using the same tutorial, but my requirement is bit more complex like use windows authentication but use userinfo and roleinfo from the sql database